# Cancel heist in GTA Online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

When I replay a heist, then cancel the heist like 2 days later, will the next heist lester calls me about be the heist after the heist that I unlocked last, or will it be the heist after the one I played last? For example, if I play Series A funding, finish it, then go back and play humane raid, cancel that on the second setup, will lester then call me and give me series A or will he give me the pacific standard job?

Answer (score 2):

To unlock the next heist, you have to complete the previous one, so if you cancel it, you will have to re-do it until you complete the final mission of the heist..